# How to update Overview/Changelog of cocoapods page

Tags: ios, cocoapods

As I can see there are multiple complains already filed against not updating changelog/overview, this problem exists in their side, Cocoapods team is working on it but it is not fixed. (existing complains- https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoadocs.org/issues/589) .

There is a webhook present to update the same but that is only for open-source projects but I own a private project, I am not able to change the overview page.

Admob has removed all the changelog and readme from their cocoapod and put a short version independent snippet(ref:-https://cocoapods.org/pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK)
I am also trying to do the same, can anyone help me how to update the same?